# How can the function $\phi_1 (x) = x^2 \quad \& \quad \phi_2(x) = x |x|$ be linearly independent ?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, independence

In the book of *Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations* by Coddington , at page 64 in question 3, it is asked to

> show that the functions  $$\phi_1 (x) = x^2 \quad \& \quad \phi_2(x) = x |x|$$
>   are linearly independent on $- \infty < x < \infty$.

However, I do not understand how can this be ?

I mean if we restrict ourselves to positive and negative values of $x$, the function $\phi_2$ becomes $$\phi_2(x) = \pm x^2,$$
respectively, hence in either case, they are linearly dependent, so what am I missing in here ?

Comment: Take a close look at the definition of linearly independent.  Note that are no non-zero values of $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1 \phi_1 + c_2 \phi_2$ is *the zero function for all $x$*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, I see. You are right.

Comment: I think anotehr approach should be: $\phi_1$ is differentiable at $0$, whereas $\phi_2$ not, so you can't writhe $\phi_1$ as a lienar combination that involves $\phi_2$.

Comment: @Dog_69 Good observation, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword is for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Suppose $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$,$$c_1 \phi_1(x)+c_2\phi_2(x)=0$$

$$c_1x^2+c_2|x|x=0$$

If $x=1$, we have $c_1+c_2=0$.

If $x=-1$, we have $c_1-c_2=0$.

Hence we have $c_1=c_2=0$.